# bash: convert array into string preserving white spaces

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, array, whitespace

I am just trying to convert an array into string, while preserving the white spaces. This is what I have:

```
INPUT=$1
readarray -t arr < <(grep -o . <<< "$INPUT")

echo "${arr[*]}"
```

I tried it with `${parameter//pat/string}`, setting IFS to `IFS=' '` and its obviously wrong. I am unable to produce the desired output.

`printf %q "$IFS"` outputs `$' \t\n'`

I run my script with command `./rev_arr "I'm Hungry!"`

Output: [image]

Expected Output: [image]

Comment: `... grep -o '.\+' <<< "$INPUT"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't quite see the usefulness of reading a string as separate characters into an array, just to re-form the string again, setting `IFS` to a single space will insert a single space between the elements of the array when using `"${arr[*]}"`.  Instead, set `IFS` to an empty string:

```
readarray -t arr < <( grep -o . <<<"$1" )
( IFS=''; printf '%s\n' "${arr[*]}" )
```

I'm using a subshell for the assignment to `IFS` and for the `printf` as to not change the value of `IFS` for the rest of the script.

Comment: There is no need to change IFS, a `printf '%s' "${arr[@]}"; echo` works perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a `*` in `"${arr[*]}"` is introducing the *first character* from IFS as separator for each element of the array. You could try a change of IFS:

```
 readarray -t arr < <(grep -o . <<< "$input")
 ( IFS=''; echo "${arr[*]}" )
```

Or try a complex evaluation delay with eval:

```
 readarray -t arr < <(grep -o . <<< "$input")
 IFS='' eval 'echo "array= ${arr[*]}"'
```

But there is no real need to start a subshell (to avoid changing the IFS in the present shell) or a risk increasing eval when a simple printf is all you need:

```
 readarray -t arr < <(grep -o . <<< "$input")
 printf '%s' "${arr[@]}" $'\n'
```

Note that the use of grep will remove any internal newlines from `$input`.

To be able to get the newlines in the array elements (for small inputs):

```
 [[ $input =~ ${input//?/(.)} ]] && arr=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}")
 printf '%s' array= "${arr[@]}" $'\n'
```